# Odoo 13: Creating invoice from purchase order in odoo via api

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, xml-rpc, odoo-13

I am brand new to odoo!  On odoo 13 EE I am trying to create and confirm a vendor bill after importing a purchase order and the item receipts.  I can create an invoice directly, but haven't been able to link that to the PO/receipt?

Sadly under purchase.order the method action_create_invoice seems hidden from the API

```
order_id = PurchaseOrder.create(po)
purchaseorder = PurchaseOrder.browse([order_id])
print("Before validating:", purchaseorder.name, purchaseorder.state) # draft
odoo.env.context['check_move_validity'] = True
purchaseorder.button_confirm()
purchaseorder = PurchaseOrder.browse([order_id])
picking_count = purchaseorder.picking_count
print("After Post:", purchaseorder.name, purchaseorder.state, "picking_count = ", purchaseorder.picking_count)
if picking_count == 0:
print("Nothing to receive. Straight to to Billing.") # ok so far
 tryme = purchaseorder.action_view_invoice()
## Error => odoorpc.error.RPCError: type object 'purchase.order' has no attribute 'action_create_invoice'
```

SO I tried overriding/extending this way

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
 _inherit = 'purchase.order'
 @api.model
def create_invoice(self, context=None):
# try 1 => odoorpc.error.RPCError: 'super' object has no attribute      # 'action_create_invoice'
rtn = super().action_create_invoice(self)

# try2 => odoorpc.error.RPCError: name 'action_create_invoice' is         # not defined
 # rtn = action_create_invoice(self)

 # try3 => Error %s 'super' object has no attribute '       #         action_create_invoice'
 # rtn = super(models.Model, self).action_create_invoice(self)
return rtn
```

I hope somebody can suggest a solution!  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please dont customize it without having a functional knowledge in odoo. In odoo, if you go to purchase settings, you can find billing options under invoicing where you can find 2 options, ordered quantity and received quantity. if it is ordered quantity, then you can create invoice after confirming the Purchase order. if it is received quantity, then after confirming the purchase order, a incoming shipment will be created and after the incoming shipment is processed, you can find the create invoice button in purchase order

Answer (score 0):

If you can do it from the browser client, than you should just look what API commands the browser sends to the odoo server (in Chrome by enabling the debug view by pressing F12, and looking in the network tab), so that you just need to copy that communication.